# MATLAB: $\tt freqz$ vs $\tt bode$

Tags: matlab, filters, frequency-response

I started studying DSP recently. In my MATLAB assignments, I am often asked to plot the frequency response of a digital filter using `freqz`. I know there's another function for plotting a frequency response, `bode`.

In my last assignment, I was asked to design a notch filter for $60\textrm{ Hz}$ with a sampling frequency of $200\textrm{ Hz}$. After doing so, I plotted the frequency response using `freqz`, which gave me the expected result - the notch was on $60\textrm{ Hz}$:

[image: freqz plot]

However, when I plot the frequency response using `bode`, the frequency is off significantly:

[image]

To my understanding, both functions measure the frequency response. Why is one giving me the correct result then, when the other is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*freqz()* plot uses a discrete-time frequency axis, linearly scaled, between $0$ and $1$, ($\times \pi$) radians per sample. For 200 Hz sampling frequency, a 60 Hz notch would be shown at $w_c = 0.6 \pi$ rads, which is put at frequency 0.6.

The Bode-plot, however, uses a **logarithmic** scale for the continuous-time radian frequency $\Omega$. Given that you have a notch frequency of $60$ Hz, corresponding radian value is $\Omega_c = 2\pi \times  60 \approx 377$ radians per second.

So both plots are showing the notch at the correct place.

Comment: Thank you. I screwed up the conversion from Hz to radians.